# bootstrap column ordering with 4 columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to do column ordering with bootstrap .On desktop screen i want this order.

```
------ --------------------
|a    |b         |c        |
------|          |----------  
      |          |d        |
      |          |----------
       ----------
```

On small screen, i want this order.

```
------ -----------
 |a    |b         |
 ------|          |  
 |c    |          |
 ------|----------|
 |d    |
 -------
```

from my code, i get this. Before the images above were wrong. Now I have changed to right images above.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-4" style="color:black;background:yellow">A
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6" style="color:white;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12    " style="color:white;background:green">B<br>B<br>B<br>B</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-8  " style="color:white;background:red">C</div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-pull-8   " style="color:white;background:blue">D</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290704/2314737). And if you have a different question, post a new one

Comment: I rolled back to your original question because "_Drastically changing a question - especially one with answers -_ [ ... ]  _invalidates all the work the answerer(s) put into their answer(s)._" See: [How much change to the question is too much?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290297/how-much-change-to-the-question-is-too-much)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you trying to achieve?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div style="background-color:yellow">
                                1
                            </div>
                            <div style="background-color:green">
                                2
                            </div>
                            <div style="background-color:red">
                                3
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                            <div style="background-color:blue">
                                4
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: 'small screen' image was wrong. i don't know why. i have changed the 'small screen image again. basically what i want is to stack in small screen in this order a,b,c,d.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one row with two columns of equal size (of class `col-sm-6`).

Under the leftmost column you nest three rows, that do not need a class because they occupy by default all the available horizontal space (same answer as [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44685833/2314737) )

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div style="color:black;background:yellow">A</div>
    <div style="color:white;background:red">C</div>
    <div style="color:white;background:blue">D</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div style="color:white;background:green">B<br>B<br>B<br>B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 'small screen' image was wrong. i don't know why. i have changed the 'small screen image' again. basically what i want is to stack in small screen in this order a,b,c,d