# bootstrap column ordering 4 columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am doing column ordering with 4 columns.In big screen, i want it like this.

```
-------  ----------
|a    |  |b       |
-------  |        |  
|c    |  |        |  
-------  |        |  
|d    |  ----------
-------
```

In small screen, i want to stack in order, a,b,c,d, as shown below.

```
--------
|a     |
--------
|b     |
--------
|c     |
--------
|d     |
--------
```

Below is my code.

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-4"style="color:black;background:yellow">A
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6"style="">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12    "style="color:white;background:green">B<br>B<br>B<br>B</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-8  "style="color:white;background:red">C</div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-pull-8   "style="color:white;background:blue">D</div>
      </div>
  </div> 

</div>
```

Comment: Should your `b` has that big content or you want that much space?

Comment: B content is dynamic. If users add content, b content will get bigger in terms of height.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bootstrap column ordering with 4 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44684912/bootstrap-column-ordering-with-4-columns)